# Facebook Open Graph multiple objects posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

How do I apply action on multiple objects in one post? e.g. John Doe bought "Item A" and "Item B" via MyApp

I see the examples of the sentences in the action settings in the dashboard, and if those sentences exist there, there should be a way to post them, but I couldn't figure out how.

"User took {photo1} and {photo2} using AppName"
"User took {photo1} and {photo count other photos} using AppName"

I tried posting to the link: http://graph.facebook.com/namespace:action/object with object=url_object1 and another object=url_object2 , tried object={url_object1,url_object2} , nothing works, nor is there any documentation of facebook as of how to do this.

p.s. seriously? can't add images without reputation?

Comment: Facebook is creating those sentences by aggregating similar actions, you have no control over that

Comment: I see... can I somehow enforce this condition, by posting multiple objects in a specific time frame?

Comment: If you post mote than one action in a certain time frame then it will get aggregated, it also depends on when the viewer sees this. You just need to post actions as you see fit, then facebook will aggregate things for you.

Comment: For someone who needs information for Open Graph of facebook. My conclusion is this is being depreciated or already depreciated. For more information refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348480/how-to-post-through-facebook-open-graph-for-game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You post two separate actions

```
user brought object1
user brought object2
```

Facebook may, or may not, aggregate these into a single story.