# Posting Open Graph Story with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Posting story like this works fine for me

```
FB.api('/me/<appname>:added', 'post',
                    {location:
                        {type: "<appname>:location",
                            "title": "London"
                            }},
                    function(response) {
                        if (!response || response.error) {
                        } else {
                        }
                    });
```

But I couldn't find normal documentation how to post multiple objects (in my case "locations") in one action, so user will see it as "Joe added London, Paris and NY with ".

[Only something looks same is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729861/facebook-open-graph-multiple-objects-posting).

So the main question: "is it correct, that I need to post multiple pairs action->object, and then FB maybe will agregate them?"

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is YES, Facebook will agregate stories itself.