# How to post through Facebook Open Graph for game

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am developing some quiz app, and want to post player's achievement on facebook.

Since I want to post the image for the achievement and Link Share of facebook doesn't support add image any more, I decided to use Open Graph.

I succeeded to post with example source for the object type of "fitness.course", but still have troubles with the object type of "game.achievement".

Share Dialog shows up, and seems OK until I click post button. But, after clicking post button, I cannot find the post on my facebook wall.

Here is my source code.

```
    // Set image with the image on the file path
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalImageFilePath);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();

    // set object
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "game.achievement")
            .putString("og:title", "App Name")
            .putString("og:description", "You achieved Golden madal")
            .putInt("game:point", 100)
            .build();

    // set action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("games.achieves")
            .putObject("game.achievement", object)
            .putPhoto("image", photo)
            .build();

    // set content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("game.achievement")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    mShareDialog.show(content);
```

For your information, the below is the example source code I succeeded with

```
    // Set image with the image on the file path
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalImageFilePath);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
           .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
           .putString("og:title", "App Name")
           .putString("og:description", "You achieved Golden madal")
           .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
           .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
           .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
           .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
           .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
           .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
           .build();

   ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
           .setActionType("fitness.runs")
           .putObject("fitness:course", object)
           .putPhoto("image", photo)
           .build();

   ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
           .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
           .setAction(action)
           .build();
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your efforts.

Comment: I categorized my test app as games in facebook configuration.  Curiously I succeeded with fitness object, and failed with game object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got the reason for this.  It is so disappointing.  Open Graph for game.achievement seems to have been depreciated. See the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements?locale=en_US

> The Scores API and Achievements API are slated for deprecation. As of
>   April 4, 2018, they will only return empty data sets and will be
>   deprecated in the near future. Please see the changelog for more
>   information.

Also facebook depreciated Custom Open Graph.  See the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom-open-graph-deprecation